# How close sort selection options after making selection in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sorting, filter

I have a sorting filter set up for a photo gallery which for the most part works great.  Except, when selecting to use it, after clicking on an item, the options box does not automatically close.  I have to click back up on the top of the selection box to get it to close.  But most users won't know to do that and it covers up the data beneath.  It's a pain.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Am not super technical, so please be detailed.  Thank you.

```
<div class="sorting_options clearfix">


                            <!-- filter_block -->
                            <div id="options" class="product_sort">
                                <div class="filterhouse_btn"><span class="sorting_options_text">Select Your Model</span><span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span><div class="clear"></div></div>
                                <ul id="filter" class="option-set" data-option-key="filter">

                                    <li><a class="" href="#filter" data-option-value=".arrow">The Arrow</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="" href="#filter" data-option-value=".berry">The Berry</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="" href="#filter" data-option-value=".cypress">The Cypress</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="" href="#filter" data-option-value=".dog">The Dog</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="" href="#filter" data-option-value=".siteplan">Site Plan</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="" href="#filter" data-option-value=".floorplan">Floor Plans</a></li>
                                    <!--<li><a class="" href="#filter" data-option-value=".map">Map</a></li> -->
                                    <li class="current"><a class="" href="#filter" data-option-value=".arrowopen, .berryopen, .cypressopen, .dogopen, .galleryopen, .siteplanopen">Preview</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="" href="#filter" data-option-value="*">All</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <script>
                                $("#filter").hide();
                                $(".filterhouse_btn, #filter li a").click(function() {
                                    $("#filter").slideToggle("fast");
                                });
                            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if its a typo cos you pasted the code in here - but you are not closing the parent (sorting_options) div in the above code. I just pasted your code into a working page and the div closes as expected if that div is closed in the code.

```js
$("#filter").hide();
$(".filterhouse_btn, #filter li a").click(function() {
  $("#filter").slideToggle("fast");
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sorting_options clearfix">

  <!-- filter_block -->
  <div id="options" class="product_sort">
    <div class="filterhouse_btn">
      <span class="sorting_options_text">Select Your Model</span><span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <ul id="filter" class="option-set" data-option-key="filter">
      <li><a class="" href="#filter" data-option-value=".arrow">The Arrow</a></li>
      <li><a class="" href="#filter" data-option-value=".berry">The Berry</a></li>
      <li><a class="" href="#filter" data-option-value=".cypress">The Cypress</a></li>
      <li><a class="" href="#filter" data-option-value=".dog">The Dog</a></li>
      <li><a class="" href="#filter" data-option-value=".siteplan">Site Plan</a></li>
      <li><a class="" href="#filter" data-option-value=".floorplan">Floor Plans</a></li>
      <!--<li><a class="" href="#filter" data-option-value=".map">Map</a></li> -->
      <li class="current"><a class="" href="#filter" data-option-value=".arrowopen, .berryopen, .cypressopen, .dogopen, .galleryopen, .siteplanopen">Preview</a></li>
      <li><a class="" href="#filter" data-option-value="*">All</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have the closing div after all of the sorting elements.  If I add it here, it causes the elements to be disregarded.  So, no, unfortunately, this did not fix the problem.